# "You can't learn a musical instrument ______________ you practise every day"

Tags: word-request, exam-questions

I was trying to do a PET sample test, and I found the following sentence reconstruction exercise, they were easy; but there's a sentence that I couldn't complete, this is the sentence:

> "If you want to learn a musical instrument, you need to practise every day."
>
> "You can't learn a musical instrument ______________ you practise every day"

How can I fill it?

Comment: That's a horrible question. It's too ambiguous as Adam's answer demonstrates.

Comment: Yeah..Unless is the perfect answer.

Comment: Judging by the wording of the example sentence, I'm guessing they intended "if you don't".

Comment: The PET writing exercise also specifies that the transformed sentence MUST have the SAME meaning as the original, and the gap  MUST NOT contain more than three words (1-3 words). All things which the OP didn't think to mention, and which allowed Adam's answer to be highly upvoted. Please consider the fact that a user or visitor may not have the time or inclination to read the comments and think the answers proposed by Adam are acceptable. They're not. Except for **unless**, which is the ONLY answer that fits when you know the aforementioned constraints.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One possible answer is "unless."

> You can't learn a musical instrument **unless** you practise every day

The same sentence could also begin with the "unless" clause, in which case *unless* means "if not" e.g. *if you don't ...*

> **Unless** you practice every day, you can't learn a musical instrument.

Answer (score 50):

NOTE:  The question originally did not include the sentence that provides context.  Given that context, "unless" is the only sensible choice.  I am leaving this answer up to illustrate some of the options that would be available if the context was not provided.

---

The other respondent's answer (*unless*) is likely the expected one.  There are other possibilities that make some kind of sense, and would be perfectly grammatical:

---

> You can't learn a musical instrument ***unless*** you practise every day."

If you don't practice daily, you will not learn to play.  This is probably the "correct" answer.

---

> You can't learn a musical instrument ***if*** you practise every day."

Your mind needs to rest a little - take occasional  breaks from practicing if you wish to learn faster.

---

> You can't learn a musical instrument ***because*** you practise every day."

Similar to the previous one - daily practice is hampering your progress.

---

> You can't learn a musical instrument ***until*** you practise every day."

You have been wasting your time with occasional practices.  Change your behavior and start practicing more, or you won't learn.

---

> You can't learn a musical instrument ***even if*** you practise every day."

You are a fat-fingered, tin-eared incompetent.  You will never learn to play an instrument.  Give up now.  ***Although*** would also work here.

Comment: Out of the answers so far, until and unless are the only two that really fit/ make sense IMO.

Comment: I upvoted simply because of your final point, that was hilarious xD

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

> You can't learn a musical instrument **before** you practise every day.

Answer (score -2):

*'excepting that'* is also another possible answer, but less likely than *'unless'*

> You can't learn a musical instrument, excepting that you practice everyday

Meaning you can learn in the exceptional circumstance that you practice every day. I don't know who would say that really.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not just "less likely than 'unless'", it's [archaic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excepting+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexcepting%20that%3B%2Cc0) and sounds stilted in Modern (Standard) English.  It is definitely not what a standardized exam (the PET) would be looking for.

Comment: *... "except if" you practice every day* would be acceptable